# Filter runningApplications List?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I am trying to know if application has UI or its a agent or application without UI.

My approach is to use,

```
NSArray *runningApplicationsList = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
```

In `runningApplicationsList` has entry of applications like iTunesHelper, AirPortBaseStationAgent, iChatAgent, AppleSpell, etc.

I am looking for way to filter them out? Can anyone suggest an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try grabbing the `NSRunningApplication` instance for each app, then check the `activationPolicy`.   It should be `NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited` if the app can't be activated (doesn't have a UI).

If that doesn't work, then you'll likely have to poke about at per-app window lists, but I'm not sure if that is possible without elevated privileges.

Comment: NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited solves the problem. Thanks! :)